# Why do cars in Need For Speed: Most Wanted pulls towards right only?

Tags: controllers, android, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I am playing Need For Speed: Most Wanted on an Android phone but the car always pulls towards right. How to get rid of that? Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the problem here is with Need for Speed: Most Wanted.

This sounds like something was poorly calibrated. Maybe a [gyroscope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope)? Someone on Android Stack Exchange was having that problem, and here is a [fix](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59532/how-can-i-calibrate-the-tilting-sensor-on-android):

> Method 1:
>
> Open "Settings"
>
> Find "Motion" and tap on it
>
> Scroll down the menu and tap on "Sensitivity Setting"
>
> Open "Gyroscope calibration"
>
> Place device on a level surface and tap Calibrate